# Having trouble with binary trees - Trying to check something by levels in C#

Tags: c#, binary-tree

I have a binary tree when each leaf consists of:

```
 BinNode<Tuple<int,int>>
```

The first item is the value of the leaf, and the second item is a level.

I'm trying to make a function that get this binary tree and check if the values at each double level(0,2,4..) are listed in ascending order from left to right **and** If the values in each non-double level(1,3,5..) are sorted in descending order from left to right

I made an example for tree that the function need to return true:

[image]

The BinNode Class has the following functions:

> T GetValue()
>
> BinNode GetLeft()
>
> BinNode GetRight()
>
> bool HasLeft()
>
> bool HasRight()

I tried something but it did not work:

```
public static bool CheckTheTree(BinNode<Tuple<int, int>> t)
        {
        Queue < BinNode <Tuple<int, int>>> queue = new Queue<BinNode<Tuple<int, int>>>();
        queue.Insert(t);

        BinNode<Tuple<int, int>> last = null;
        while (!queue.IsEmpty())
        {
            if (last == null)
            {
                last = queue.Remove();
            }
            else
            {
                BinNode<Tuple<int, int>> current = queue.Remove();

                int current_level = current.GetValue().Item2;
                int last_level = last.GetValue().Item2;

                int current_value = current.GetValue().Item1;
                int last_value = last.GetValue().Item1;

                if (current_level == last_level)
                {
                    if ((current_level % 2 == 0 && current_value < last_value)
                        || (current_level % 2 == 1 && current_value > last_value)){
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (current.HasLeft())
                        queue.Insert(current.GetLeft());
                    if (current.HasRight())
                        queue.Insert(current.GetRight());
                }
                last = current;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

and the Main:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        // (8,0)
        BinNode<Tuple<int,int>> b1 = new BinNode<Tuple<int, int>>(new Tuple<int, int>(8, 0));

        // (9,1)
        b1.SetRight(new BinNode<Tuple<int, int>>(new Tuple<int, int>(9, 1)));

        // (10, 1)
        b1.SetLeft(new BinNode<Tuple<int, int>>(new Tuple<int, int>(10, 1)));


        // (-3,2)
        b1.GetLeft().SetLeft(new BinNode<Tuple<int, int>>(new Tuple<int, int>(-3, 2)));


       Console.WriteLine(CheckTheTree(b1) );
        
    }
```

Comment: Aaand what exactly is your problem? What did you try?

Comment: your picture and your text dont fit - the picture has first the value and second the level

Comment: @WhileTrueSleep thanks, i fixed the that.

Comment: @nocodename i don't know how to make the function ..

Comment: *level(0,2,4..) are listed in ascending order from left to right and If the values in each non-double level(1,3,5..) are sorted in descending order from left to right* - that seems like a really odd thing to do. What would be the purpose of such a tree?

Comment: @MattBurland I'm only responsible for building the algorithm for testing if the tree is like the example..
I don't know what the purpose of such a tree would be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use BFS. [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) (Breadth First Search) is an algorithm to loop the tree nodes in the order or their level. This algorithm uses a Queue. In your problem, you need to look at each level in the order of the nodes. You look a the current node, and if the last and current nodes have the same level, then check for the order of them, depending if Level is Odd.

I used Value and Level properties in your BinNode object for simplicity. Change it to binnode.GetValue().Value1 for Value and binnode.GetValue().Value2 for Level

It is like this:

```
public static bool CheckTheTree(BinNode<Tuple<int, int>> t){
    Queue<BinNode<Tuple<int, int>> queue = new Queue<BinNode<Tuple<int, int>>();
    queue.Enqueue(t);

    BinNode<Tuple<int, int>> last = null;
    while(queue.Any()){
        if(last = null){
            last = queue.Dequeue();
        }
        else{
            BinNode<Tuple<int, int>> current = queue.Dequeue();
            if(current.Level == last.Level){
                if((current.Level % 2 == 0 && current.Value < last.Value)
                    || (current.Level % 2 == 1 && current.Value > last.Value){
                    return false;
                }

            }

            last = current;
        }

        if(last.HasLeft())
            queue.Enqueue(last.GetLeft());
        if(last.HasRight())
            queue.Enqueue(last.GetRight());
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Why not?, please, post an incorrect input sample, so i can debug it

Comment: I debug now and the bug is:
firstly, last = null so its enter to the if ( if(last ==  null) ) and after that its not do the else and return to the while but the queue is empty so it's done and return always true

Comment: I fixed. I was always enqueing when last != null

Comment: Now I have error in:
        if(current.HasRight())
becuase current define in the else so 'current' does not exists in the current context.

and in:
            last.Enqueue(last.GetRight());
because last isn't Queue so he doesn't have Enqueue function.

Comment: change current by last

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144077/discussion-between-alejandro-perez-fals-and-yair-b).

Comment: and what about: I can't do  last.Enqueue(last.GetRight()); because 'last' isn't Queue so he doesn't have Enqueue function.

Comment: is queue.Enque(last.GetRight()). It was a mistake copyin the code. sorry

Answer (score 0):

You should walk through the algorithm on paper and see what order you are traversing the tree.  It appears that you are going right to left and maybe should be going left to right.  Also the API provides hasLeft() and hasRight() for a reason so you probably need to call them before calling getLeft() or GetRight().